# Is it possible with rpm-spec and debbuild to always install latest version of dependency?

Tags: rpm, deb, rpm-spec

Both RPM and DEB specifications has `requires` field where it is possible to specify dependencies with minimum/maximum/strict required versions.

However in my case `I always need unconditionally install latest available version` of rpm/deb of certain dependency.

Is it possible to achieve that through standard directives or is there some other way so that installing package will always install latest dependencies.

One idea would be to call `yum install` or `apt-get install` from respective hooks. But this is pretty ugly solution and I am looking for some alternative approach (if such exists).

Comment: afaik there is no such way. recursively calling `yum install`won't even work (at least with zypper I know there are locks on rpm database). Furthermore; you don't even kwow which versions will be available in the future; neither whether they will break API; so I'm not even sure if that is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

RPM itself does nothing but verify dependencies. Your question is appropriate for what depsolvers choose to implement when interpreting a dependency assertion contained in a *.rpm package.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. You either have to manually specify it. Or instruct user to always run `yum upgrade`.